# jquery onblur menu hide works in firefox not in chrome

Tags: jquery, events, firefox, google-chrome, onblur

Hi, I have some code which displays a drop-down menu when the button is clicked:

---

```
<button id="friend-requestButton" class="ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-all ui-state-default"></button>

<!--button end-->

<!--Menu markup below-->

<div class="friend-requestMenu dropdown_Menu" id="friend-requestMenu">
    <div class="menuTitle">
        Friend Requests <a href='javascript:void(0)' class="titleLink">See All</a>
    </div>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' class="menu_item">Menu Item</a>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)'>
        <div class="seeAllBlock">
            See All Requests
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
$('#friend-requestButton').click(function () {
    if ($('#friend-requestMenu').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#friend-requestMenu').css('display', 'block').show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 200);
    }
    else {
        $('#friend-requestMenu').css('display', 'none').effect('fold');
    }
})
.blur(function () {
    $('#friend-requestMenu').css('display', 'none').effect('fade');
});
```

---

The problem is that the drop-down disappears perfectly in Firefox but not in Chrome. I'm not sure if it's important, but it's basically a toolbar and the `z-index` value is at about `100`. Here is the actual page, the script contains jQuery and some plugins src'ed and the rest -> The actual code I wrote...(I'm aware it doesn't work in IE, but in Chrome the `onblur` for the buttons on the left of the search bar does not work, but it works in FF5, so it must work in lower FF's too.

Thanks a lot for the help :D

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#friend-requestButton').click(function () {
    if ($('#friend-requestMenu').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#friend-requestMenu').css('display', 'block').show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 200);
    }
    else {
        $('#friend-requestMenu').css('display', 'none').hide("fold", {}, 1000);
    }
});
$(this).blur(function () {
    $('#friend-requestMenu').css('display', 'none').effect('fade');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="friend-requestButton" class="ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-all ui-state-default"></button>

<!--button end-->

<!--Menu markup below-->

<div id="friend-requestMenu">
    <div class="menuTitle">
        Friend Requests <a href='javascript:void(0)' class="titleLink">See All</a>
    </div>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' class="menu_item">Menu Item</a>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)'>
        <div class="seeAllBlock">
            See All Requests
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works for me in Google Chrome.
What I found from researching is that your .effect('fold') does not exist in JQuery. The way you use 'fold' is within a .hide/.show like I have in my edit of your code:

`$('#friend-requestMenu').css('display', 'none').hide("fold", {}, 1000)`;

Here's a link that show's this functionality: [Fold](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Fold)

You may also want to rewrite your .effect('fade') since I only see these effects on the JQuery API: .fadeIn(), .fadeOut(), .fadeTo(), and .fadeToggle(): [Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

This is my first post so if I am wrong, let me know. This solution works for me in Chrome.

Any questions, let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: hi sgtbigman , thanks for the help, but i tried the code, doesnt seem to work. i tried removing all effects too , still doesnt blur at all....it works fine on firefox , i havent designed this for ie so no way of telling(css all scrambled up), i heard tabindex=0 attribute must be added for it to work not too sure...

Comment: @anonymouslyanonymous If you were curious, I found a solution to this problem. I apologize for the tardiness of my reply.

Answer (score 0):

@anonymouslyanonymous I apologize for never getting back to you on this and am sure you have moved on to bigger and better things, but I wanted to put this answer here for anyone that may stumble upon this thread in the future.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
      $('#friend-requestButton').click(function () {
           if ($('#friend-requestMenu').css('display') == 'none') {
                $('#friend-requestMenu').show(1000);
           }
           else {
                $('#friend-requestMenu').hide(1000);
           }
      });
 });
 </script>
```

That is the edited code that I got to work correctly in Chrome as of today. The .show(#) and .hide(#) methods allow for one to create blur effects of varying speed, etc.

I hope this helps.
Thanks.